# Not getting results into dataset from database stored procedure for displaying gridview

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have gridview which I need to populate the data by selecting the value from dropdownlist.

For this I am trying to update a stored procedure with a parameter. We are using Entity Framework database access.

But I'm not getting any results to the gridview, after I change the stored procedure.

Can anyone please help me?

```
public DataView BindReport()
{
     var user = Session["currentUser"] as UserSession;

     if (user == null) 
         return null;

     var totalrows = 0;

     var result = SalesReport.GetJobseekerReportResults(user.CompanyId,ref totalrows);
     DataView ds = ToDataTable(result).DefaultView;

     if (ViewState["SortExpr"] != null)
            ds.Sort = ViewState["SortExpr"].ToString();

     RowCount = totalrows;
     dataTable = new DataTable();
     dataTable = ds.ToTable();

     return ds;
}

private void InitializePageSize(GridView gridView)
{
    var user = Session["currentUser"] as UserSession;

    if (user == null) 
        return;

    var pageSize = GridController.GetGridSizeForUser(user.UserId, gridView.ID, user.CompanyId);

    if (pageSize == null) 
        return;

    gridView.PageSize = (int)pageSize.page_size;
    ddlSkillPageCount.SelectedValue = gridView.PageSize.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    gridView.DataBind();
}

public static List<JobseekerReport_Result> GetJobseekerReportResults(long companyid,  ref int tototalrows)
{
    var context = new NavDataEntities();
    List<JobseekerReport_Result> result = null;

    try
    {
        context.Database.Connection.Open();

        result = context.JobseekerReport(companyid).ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        context.Database.Connection.Close();
    }

    return result;
}

public virtual ObjectResult<JobseekerReport_Result> JobseekerReport(Nullable<long> cmpid)
{
    var cmpidParameter = cmpid.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("cmpid", cmpid) :
            new ObjectParameter("cmpid", typeof(long));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<JobseekerReport_Result>("JobseekerReport", cmpidParameter);
}
```

Comment: Where is the code which binds the data to GridView?

Comment: I have added the code for the GridView Binding.

Comment: Are you missing gridView.DataSource before gridView.DataBind?

Comment: I dint find any gridview.datasource. Here Entityframework database approach.

Comment: I get results from BindReport() Method, but i am not getting once i update the strored proc by adding a parameter

Comment: Where is the code for calling stored proc?

Comment: It is in public virtual ObjectResult<> at last down code.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void InitializePageSize(GridView gridView)
{
    var user = Session["currentUser"] as UserSession;
    if (user == null) return;
    var pageSize = GridController.GetGridSizeForUser(user.UserId, gridView.ID, user.CompanyId);
    if (pageSize == null) return;
    gridView.PageSize = (int)pageSize.page_size;
    ddlSkillPageCount.SelectedValue = gridView.PageSize.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    DataSet ds =  BindReport(); /// Added these two lines.
    gridView.DataSource = ds; ///
    gridView.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: I just added. for BindReport(), Cannot implicitly convert type system.data.dataview to system.data.dataset.

Comment: Okay, change it to DataView ds = BindReport();

Comment: but this bindreport() method using this in objectdatasource.

Comment: Sai, for a GridView to show something, 2 things are required. 1. Specify a dataSource to GridView and Bind that data. Now your bindreport is creating the data, but you are not attaching it to GridView. For that I suggested to use DataSource property of GridView. Have a look at http://www.worldbestlearningcenter.com/index_files/csharp-entity-framework-datagridview.htm

Comment: Thank you. But i am not getting records into the objectresult. I mentioned the code objectresult....

Answer (score 0):

I got the results. And now gridview is populating the results when the dropdownlist value selected.

The problem i got is with edmx model. When ever i do changes in tables or stored proc. First i need to delete the edmx model from solution and then add it again.

Thank you.